# Loop through items in HTML table using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have a table.

I want to go through all the goods and get their quality and price.
But i can't figure out how to get these values.

table:

```
<div class="table-items__container">
    <div class="table-items__item">
        <div class="item_name">Name</div>
        <div class="item_quality">1</div>
        <div class="item_price">30</div>
        <div class="table-items_item__controls">
            <a href=""><i class="fas fa-edit"></i></a>
            <a href=""><i class="fas fa-trash"></i></a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="table-items__item">
        <div class="item_name">Name</div>
        <div class="item_quality">2</div>
        <div class="item_price">20</div>
        <div>
            <a href=""><i class="fas fa-edit"></i></a>
            <a href=""><i class="fas fa-trash"></i></a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="table-items__item">
        <div class="item_name">Name</div>
        <div class="item_quality">3</div>
        <div class="item_price">10</div>
        <div>
            <a href=""><i class="fas fa-edit"></i></a>
            <a href=""><i class="fas fa-trash"></i></a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="Summary">Summary: <span></span></div>
```

Script:

```
$('.table-items__item').children().each(function(){
    console.log($(this).text());
});
```

I think that's all needed.

Then I need to calculate the price of all items.

http://jsfiddle.net/mg4wjfbu/

Comment: [jQuery Learning Center](https://learn.jquery.com)

Comment: What is problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Iterate over the wrapped div and within the callback function get element within current div by specifying [context argument](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery-selector-context) or using [`find()`](https://api.jquery.com/find/) method(within callback `this` refers to the current element).

```js
$('.table-items__item').each(function() {
  console.log($('.item_quality', this).text(), $('.item_price', this).text());
  
  // or
  console.log($(this).find('.item_quality').text(), $(this).find('.item_price').text());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="table-items__container">
  <div class="table-items__item">
    <div class="item_name">Name</div>
    <div class="item_quality">1</div>
    <div class="item_price">30</div>
    <div class="table-items_item__controls">
      <a href=""><i class="fas fa-edit"></i></a>
      <a href=""><i class="fas fa-trash"></i></a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="table-items__item">
    <div class="item_name">Name</div>
    <div class="item_quality">2</div>
    <div class="item_price">20</div>
    <div>
      <a href=""><i class="fas fa-edit"></i></a>
      <a href=""><i class="fas fa-trash"></i></a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="table-items__item">
    <div class="item_name">Name</div>
    <div class="item_quality">3</div>
    <div class="item_price">10</div>
    <div>
      <a href=""><i class="fas fa-edit"></i></a>
      <a href=""><i class="fas fa-trash"></i></a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="Summary">Summary: <span></span></div>
</div>
```